# Placing sources or graphics and tables

Tags: tables, graphics

I would place my graphic and/or my tables "sources" as shown in the picture attached to this post and I don't know how to do this? Could you help me please
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The `copyrightbox` package seems to do the job. An optional argument allows the placement of the copyright text on the left side, on the right side (default, rotated) or below the copyright box. A small correction seems to be necessary to centre captions, for some reason.

For tables, the `threeparttable` package might also be used, with the `tablenotes` environment, but its `measuredfigure` environment doesn't work well if the caption is placed *above* the figure.

Example of code for the first solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption, makecell, copyrightbox}
\captionsetup{justification = centering}
\setcellgapes{6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{Le déjeuner en fourrure\,\\\textit{Meret Oppenheim}(1914--2005)}
  \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[scale = 1.1]{dejeuner1}}{Source: Google}
\end{figure*}
\vskip1cm
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering\sffamily
  \captionsetup{font = sf}
  \caption{Matrix Important/Urgent\,}
  \makegapedcells
  \copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    Labels & Urgent & Not urgent\\
    \hline
    Important & 55\,\% & 25\,\%\\
    \hline
    Not important & 20\,\% & 0\,\%\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}{Source: Google}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Untested as you don't provide an MWE but a simplified version of code I use. Add `xparse` to the packages you load in your preamble.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \imgsrc { O {Source} +m }{%
  \footnotesize #1:\thinspace
  #2\par}
```

Then you can say

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{Stuff}
stuff

\imgsrc{Fine Images}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\imgsrc[Data source]{Fine Data}
```